# Website returns 404 error for www links

Tags: wordpress, http, web, dns, http-status-code-404

Link that works: http://chinacashbuyers.com/course
Links that doesn't work (404 error): www.chinacashbuyers.com/course

The issue is that when I go to `www.link` it doesn't work, it gets a 404 error. 
How can I fix it? Do I change something in the DNS server where I bought the domain? (godaddy)

Can anyone help me on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom name-server then you need to add your server with both

www.abc.com and abc.com

you can check this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B4xNNyb5y7o)

Hope it helps ..

Answer (score 0):

Create virtual host with www.domain.com.and add below code in your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Or

define siteurl and home url in your config file.

```
define(SITEURL,'http://www.yourdomain.com');
define(HOME,'http://www.yourdomain.com');
```

or

Update your options table value for option name home and siteurl and change your server name in httpd.conf file and directory name with www.yourdomain.com